# Создание .so файлов

Tags: unix, solaris, библиотеки, компиляция, linux

Есть набор с-файлов с расширением .с: avl_tree.c, buf_read.c, db_prep.c, file_process.c, global_header.c, traverser.c. Как из них создать один .so файл (если можно укажите все опции в этой команде)? Это меня интересует в связи созданием native методов с помощью JNI. Используемые include файлы находятся в папке /usr/gcc/4.4/bin/include за исключением jni.h, а библиотеки находятся в папке /usr/gcc/4.4/bin/lib.

Comment: Смотрите

     -shared -fpic

А что не получается?

Comment: @alexlz ,Я в линуксе не сильно разбираюсь, поэтому хочу спросить, что означает опции -shared и -fpic? Не могли вы полностью привести тект команды с учетом информации, которую я вам дал?

Comment: Я не знаком с JNI и не знаю, какие требования оно предъявляет к библиотекам .so (имена, расположение, зарегистрированность в системе с помощь ld.conf ...). В принципе 

    gcc -shared -fpic -o libyuor.so vl_tree.c, buf_read.c, db_prep.c, file_process.c, global_header.c, traverser.c

-shared -- создание библиотеки .so

-fpic -- позиционно-независимый код (требование linux на x86)

Краткий туториал: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Comment: @alexlz, а у меня Nexenta 64 bit,  в таком случае нужно использовать -fpic -- позиционно-независимый код (требование linux на x86)? И что такое опции -Wl и -Map=your.map?

Comment: Про -fpic на 64бит -- не знаю (но думаю, что хуже не будет. Если они не применимы, то и использоваться не будут). Про опции. -Wl, -- опции линкера ld, т.е. -Map=your.map передаётся ld и означает просто создание map-файла (карта памяти бинарника для программиста). Если Вы её смотреть не собираетесь, то можно и не указывать необязательно. Но вот при построении .so возможно надо будет указывать какие-то библиотеки jni, про которые я ничего не знаю -- тут уж сами смотрите.

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc avl_tree.c buf_read.c db_prep.c file_process.c global_header.c traverser.c -o libkuku.so -shared -fPIC -Iпуть_к_jni.h -O2
```

Параметр -shared означает, что создается разделяемая библиотека, -fPIC - что нужно компилировать позиционно независимый бинарный файл (нужно для создания разделяемой библиотеки). -I - указывает путь к хедерам, расположенным в нестандартных местах.

Comment: @mikillskegg , а чтотакое опция -O2 в конце команды?

Comment: Это оптимизация. Блин, да почитайте что-нибудь. Полно книг, материалов в интернете. Гугль сегодня работает. Что за беспомощность?

Comment: @mikilskegg, Ты сердишься -- значит Ты не прав.

Comment: Не, я просто молодежь воспитываю. Когда я сержусь он-лайн, от моих эмоций сервера перегорают.