# Как вернуть указатель на структуру?

Tags: c++

Возник вопрос как  вернуть указатель на структуру.
Знаю, что main ничего не возвращает,но как еще можно вернуть значения?

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>


using namespace std;
using namespace pqxx;

const char* sql = "";



struct SqlSelect{
  int id;
  char name;
}

void String_One( char* msg)
{
  string s(msg);
   
    sql = msg;
    
  
}

void connect() {
   
    try {
      connection C("dbname=user user=user  password=user  hostaddr=127.0.0.1");
       if (C.is_open()) {
          cout << "Opened database successfully: " << C.dbname() << endl;
       } else {
          cout << "Can't open database" << endl;
          return 1;
       }
 
     
          SqlSelect select;

      nontransaction N(C);
         result R( N.exec( sql ));
           for (result::const_iterator c = R.begin(); c != R.end(); ++c) {
              
            select->id = c[0].as<int>();
            select->name = c[1].as<const char*>();
            

             //как здесь вернуть указатель на структуру?        
          }
          
    
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
       cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
 
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Во-первых, `main` возвращает `int`, во вторых, вернуть просто указатель - ну, типа, `&var`. Только адрес **не локальной** переменной!

Comment: Ничего не понятно, объясните нормально. Из какой функции вы хотите его вернуть? Из `main`? Если да, то зачем?

Comment: @Harry мне нужно ,чтобы в результате работы функции connect у меня были результаты запроса к БД (id=1,id=2,name=name1,name=name2). И я не знаю как мне это сделать. Вернуть это нужно ,чтобы потом записать эти значения в переменную

Comment: Как понимаю, это продолжение предыдущего вопроса QWERTYU о создании плагина к питону

Comment: Вы вроде бы недавно задавали вопрос, где пытались вернуть из `main` значение, отличное от `int`. И там в комментариях вам уже писали, что так делать не нужно...

Comment: @Юрий Козлов да,а какие-то проблемы с эттим?

Comment: @wololo только я так и не узнал как нужно

Comment: @QWERTYU, нет, проблем как таковых нет, просто пояснил для тех, кто не видел предыдущий вопрос. Что же касается самого вопроса, мне кажется Вы несколько не в ту сторону копаете. Вернуть из `main` внятно вряд ли получится. Попробуйте почитать что-то типа [этого](https://habr.com/ru/post/469043/). Не уверен, что это именно то ,что Вам нужно, но может подтолкнет к решению.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это проблема XY.

Comment: @user7860670 вот мне помощь нужна,а вы тут лишь бы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе уже выяснили, что тут имеет место проблема XY. Конечно можно и дальше пытаться забивать гвозди микроскопом, но толку от этого будет мало. Собственно указатель можно вернуть, написав правильный тип возвращаемого значения функции вместо `void` и сделав `return pointer;`, предварительно убедившись, что возвращаемый указатель останется валидным после возвращения из функции, - это же азы языка. Однако вашей реальной задаче это не особо поможет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ переоткройте вопрос, я не могу ответить, как вернуть запрос PostgreSQL.

Comment: @AlexGlebe я могу тут как-то переоткрыть вопрос?

Comment: быстрее будет новый чёткий вопрос : "как вернуть значение SQL запроса от PostgreSQL". И самому написать неудачную попытку вернуть структуру `SqlSelect`. как вам уже показали в ответе.

Comment: @AlexGlebe _быстрее будет новый чёткий вопрос_, совершенно верно. Раз вы уже подготовили ответ, то вы можете создать самоответ - вопрос на основе текущего улучшив его качество, ну и сам ответ. И все доволны будут, вкл. ТС (он посмотрит хоть, как вопросы надо задавать).

Comment: @AlexGlebe вопрос переоткрыт

Answer (score 0):

После завершения программы (main), впрочем, как и при выходе из любой функции, вся автоматическая память, то есть память, выделенная в стеке для локальных переменных функции, освобождается.

сам select не возвратится никак из программы. При возврате из функции в вызывающую функцию переменная select возвращается в виде копии (если не рассматривать механизм &&).

SqlSelect connect() {
SqlSelect select;
...
return select;
}

Если это плагин к чему-то, то надо смотреть, какой интерфейс и как он организован между хостом и плагином. Если в виде dll - то можно вызвать как обычную функцию и return select.

Если это exe со своим main, то я не знаю, может можно выводить в выходной поток cout и на стороне хоста парсить эту строку.

Comment: на самом деле нужно возвращать массив `SqlSelect*`. При SQL запросе возвращаются несколько записей (или NULL).

Comment: @AlexGlebe как мне правильно записать возврат массива? У меня файл этот используется в качестве dll

Comment: вычисляете размер списка делаете `new SqlSelect[размер]`. записываете и возвращаете. google : "вернуть массив".

Comment: @AlexGlebe я не понял как записать. мне нужна структура или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Очень подробно всё написано в https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_c_cpp.htm

Вы почему-то в функцию `connect` хотите дописать какой-то запрос. Имя функции должно быть таким, каким и действие. Напишите сначала функцию `connect`, потом `select`. Выводить результаты можно указателем на полученные значения. Выделяете память делаете задачу и возвращаете указатель.

Например, сначала подключаемся.

```
// возвращаем удачное подключение или nullptr
connection * connect ( void ) {
  try {
      connection * const C = new connection (
        "dbname = testdb user = postgres password = cohondob "\
        "hostaddr = 127.0.0.1 port = 5432");
      if (C->is_open()) {
         cout << "Opened database successfully: " << C->dbname() << endl;
      } else {
         delete C;
         cout << "Can't open database" << endl;
         return nullptr;
      }
      return C ;
   } catch (const std::exception &e) {
      cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
      return nullptr;
   }}
```

После удачного подключение вы сможете выполнять запросы. Аргументом будет служить удачное подключение и дополнительные аргументы для запроса. Результатом запроса будет служить массив структур. А какие структуры это уже в зависимости от запроса. Например запрос имени от идентификатора может возратить только одну запись или ничего. Тогда результатом функции будет указатель равный структуре или nullptr (если ответ был пустым).

```
struct SqlSelect {
  int id ;
  std :: string name; 
} ;

SqlSelect * select_id_name(connection & C ) {
  
    /* Create a non-transactional object. */
      nontransaction N(C);
      
      /* Execute SQL query */
      result R( N.exec( "SELECT id , name FROM tablename WHERE id = 1 " ));

   if(R.begin() == R.end())
     // если запрос ничего не возратил
     return nullptr ;

   // если запрос прошёл, то выделяем память для структуры 
   // и записываем значения. Потом возвращаем её.
   SqlSelect * select = new SqlSelect;
   result::const_iterator c = R.begin();
   select -> id = c[0].as<int>();
   select -> name = c[1].as<std::string>();
   return select ;
  }
```

Comment: как мне теперь составить заголовочный файл для dll?

Comment: появляется ошибка 
error: ‘select’ was not declared in this scope
          *select -> id = c[0].as<int>();

Comment: уменя всё без ошибок : `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic postgresql.cpp -std=c++14 -c` => Ok . Про `dll` спрашивайте у другого, я с виндой не работаю.

Comment: чтобы создать .so файл что мне надо?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/155413/Создание-so-файлов

Comment: я не понимаю здесь немного. есть две функции connect и select_id_name. какой тип они возвращают?

Comment: указатели на новые структуры подключения к базе и указатель на структуру результата SQL запроса.

Comment: мне нужно использовать этот файл в питоне. но для этго мне нужно обернуть с++ в с,т.к. ctypes в питоне работает с С. знаете как?

Comment: пишите не на плюсах, а на си. библиотека `libpq` вместо `libpqxx`.